# How to properly separate API calls from File Storage Service in a Clean Architecture Pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, clean-architecture, using-statement

I am working on a .NET Core project in which I need to implement a Clean Architecture Pattern. The Task is to:

1. make an HTTP request to a third-party API service
2. read the response content as a Stream
3. save the Stream Content to File Storage

In order to solve this problem, I created two classes in an infrastructure layer:

1. ApiService.cs

```
        public async Task GetDataAsync(string url, Func<Stream, Task> func)
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(url))
            {
                if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    using (Stream stream = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                    {
                        await func(stream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

2. FileStorageService.cs

```
        public async Task CreateFileAsync(string path, Stream content)
        {
            using (FileStream fileStream = new(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await content.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
        }
```

There is also a third method in Core Layer that combine and process the above two methods:

```
        public async Task DownloadData(string url, string path)
        {
            await apiService.GetDataAsync(url, async stream =>
            {
                await fileStorageService.CreateFileAsync(path, stream);
            });
        }
```

Even though the above code works there is an obvious direct dependency of File Storage Service on API Service. My Expectations are to have a clean separation of File and API service in a way that two of those do not need to know about each other. I would like to be able to have the option to implement Pipeline pattern in the future (if needed) and to be able to define the above code somehow in a way:

```
string url = "<some_url>";
Stream result = await apiService.GetDataAsync(url);

string path ="<some_path>";
await fileStorageService.CreateFileAsync(path, result);
```

I was trying to replace Func<> parameter with the Stream return type in API Service Method, but I face a challenge in properly dealing with using statements in HttpResponseMessage and Stream.

I will appreciate it a lot if you have some suggestions on how to solve the above problem in order to:

1. clearly separate API Service from File Service so that one does not know about another
2. properly dispose of the Using statements in HttpResponseMessage and Stream from apiService.GetDataAsync method without (if possible) using Func<>

Thanks in advance.

Comment: these classes are not abstracted via interfaces? With them you can make them loosely couples and not dependent on the implementations..

Comment: Yes, I do have interfaces for those two classes defined in Core Layer and implemented in Infrastructure layer. I am using dependency injection so the two methods from these two classes are called from the third method via DI (interfaces). These are not dependent on implementation but on each other which is a problem that I am trying to solve.

Comment: Could you explain the challenge you are facing with returning the stream and using statements?

Comment: Main challenge is that if you use a return keyword instead (in above case) Func<> you will have disposed object in second method which is responsible for creating a file. Basically the goal here is to follow SRP (single responsible principle) where one method is responsible for processing the http request/response and the second method is responsible for whatever you would like to do with the result of the response (create file, save to Db, read as string etc...) In one word, to have an independent stream response which can serve as a parameter in some other method in a chain without Func<>.

Comment: @VedranKnezevic You are getting disposed exception, because you are disposing the stream in the `GetDataAsync()` method, if you want to return the stream to the caller, then the `GetDataAsync()` method is not responsible anymore for disposing it and should remove the using statement.

Comment: Does same apply for Using Statement of HttpResponseMessage which is nesting the Using Statement of Stream? Are you proposing something like this: 1) HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(url) 2) return await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()

Comment: You should keep the using statement around the `HttpResponseMessage`, otherwise it wont ever be disposed, but the stream you can indeed return like this `return await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();` and then the caller of `GetDataAsync()` is responsible for disposing the stream.

Comment: And how would you read this returned stream in a Caller Method? Can you please paste line or two of example code (using it with FileStream, StreamReader etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've considered the class route, but my preferred way of dealing with this is to have a `StorageFile` and `StorageFolder` framework that mimics what UWP/Metro/etc. have had from the beginning. In fact there's a very old but still open issue in the [dotnet/runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/26403) Github repo.

The idea is simply to have abstract base classes - `StorageFile`, `StorageFolder`, and their parent `StorageObject` - that get implemented for each storage platform you want to use, from the local file system to Azure blobs to anything else.

These would be the basic definitions:

```
public abstract class StorageObject 
{
    public abstract string Name { get; }
    public abstract Task RenameAsync();
    public abstract Task<StorageProperties> GetPropertiesAsync();   // would retrieve metadata like creation/access dates, size, etc.
    public abstract Task DeleteAsync();
    public abstract Task CopyAsync (StorageFolder destination);
    public abstract Task<IEnumerable<StorageObject>> GetChildrenAsync();
}

public abstract class StorageFolder : StorageObject
{
    public abstract int Files { get; }
    public abstract int Folders { get; }
    public abstract Task<StorageFile> GetFileAsync (string filename, bool createIfNotExists);
    public abstract Task<StorageFolder> GetSubfolderAsync (string subfolderName, bool createIfNotExists);

    public virtual Task<IEnumerable<StorageFile>> FindFilesAsync (string criteria, bool includeSubfolders) { ... } // default implementation would use GetChildrenAsync but be overridable for more efficient implementations
    public virtual Task<IEnumerable<StorageFolder>> FindSubfoldersAsync (string criteria, bool includeSubfolders) { ... } // same
}

public abstract class StorageFile : StorageObject
{
    public abstract Task<Stream> OpenReadAsync(bool shared = false);
    public abstract Task<Stream> OpenWriteAsync(bool shared = false); 
}
```

So a basic (incomplete) implementation of `LocalStorageFile`, for example, would look like this:

```
public class LocalStorageFile : StorageFile 
{
   private readonly string _path;

   public LocalStorageFile (string path)
   {
      _path = path;
   } 

   public override Task<Stream> OpenReadAsync(bool shared = false)
   {
      var str = File.Open(_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, shared ? FileShare.Read : FileShare.None);
      return Task.FromResult(str);
   }

   // ...
}
```

Then you would consume it as such:

```
LocalStorageFile f = new LocalStorageFile("c:\\mypath\\file.bin");
using (var str = await f.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
{
   // do your thing
}
```

Most importantly, all the rest of your code references the base classes - `StorageFile`, etc., and so becomes completely agnostic to the implementation. And by dealing with `Stream` - another highly abstract and extensible class - you don't have to do anything special other than `Dispose` it. Of course if you have something highly specialized you can subclass `Stream` too and return whatever you want from `OpenReadAsync` and `OpenWriteAsync`.

Comment: I am not sure that this answers the main challenge here. I've already abstracted FileService Class (local storage, azure blob etc.) through interface. Please check my answer to Selmir Aljic's question above.

Comment: Hm. Sorry I guess I'm having a little trouble seeing what your exact problem is. But if it's specifically the issue of disposing the `HttpResponseMessage`, a class pattern still helps you with that because you could subclass `Stream` to wrap the `HttpResposeMessage` and its corresponding read methods and then dispose of the `HttpResponseMessage` inside your subclassed `Stream`'s `Dispose` method. Maybe that's a little bit of over-engineering but it results in a nice clean pattern.

Answer (score 0):

After discussion in comments I believe the problem lies in the fact that the stream is being disposed by the `apiService` and then the `fileStorageService` throws a disposed object exception.

A possible solution for this problem is removing the `using` statement inside the `apiService` and returning the stream.

```
    public async Task<Stream> GetDataAsync(string url)
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(url))
        {
            if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you could use it in the following way:

```
string url = "<some_url>";
Stream result = await apiService.GetDataAsync(url);

using(result)
{
    string path ="<some_path>";
    await fileStorageService.CreateFileAsync(path, result);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the stream can be read from after the `HttpResponseMessage` is disposed? I'm not certain either way but my guess would be not.

Comment: I am expecting to get "Cannot access a closed Stream" Exception in this case?

Comment: I haven’t tested it, but my guess would be it should work fine and if not then there are multiple solutions to solving the issue where both the stream and HttpResponse need to be disposed when the stream is disposed, but let’s not head in that direction if not needed :))

Comment: As  @JustAnswertheQuestion has pointed out, it should not work precisely because of disposed HttpResponseMessage. I do not like this Func<> approach but I agree as well that HttpResponseMessage Wrapper is perhaps overkill for this scenario. As this content is <300 KB and memory is not an issue, if there would be no other suggestions, I will probably read the response as a whole (string, bytes, memory stream etc.) and than decide what to do with it :)

Comment: @VedranKnezevic if that is the case, then you can indeed copy the stream to an inmemory stream and return that, or use something like RefCountDisposable to dispose both response and stream when the stream gets disposed. But to be honest I do not see a problem with your current approach there is no direct dependency between the 2 services. Another approach you could take is an in memory bus IObservable<Stream> if you want to decouple the reading and writing of the stream

Comment: Yeah, if you're CERTAIN the response is always gonna be small then I would just copy it into a `MemoryStream` and return that. But if you want something more general purpose - especially if you want to support ranged requests and such - then I would definitely consider something along the lines of my suggestion.